# Pet Safety and Adult Tricycle

Tags: accessories, tricycle, accidents, balance

Am interested in an adult tricycle and would like to add carry-on feature for my dog(slightly overweight-12lb pug mix)that can accommodate safely on either front or back. My question is about the level of safety from tipping over(or any other accidents possible) and whether the particular machinery or the rider(balance, etc) plays more of a factor in avoiding an accident. I have not heard any experiences in either direction and want to be safe(dog does, too lol) thanks!

Comment: The whole point of a trike is that they're quite difficult to tip. _Can_ you tip one? Yeah, sure, but you've got to really work at it. Avoiding accidents is the same on a trike as it is on a bike - you have to pay attention to what's around you and learn to anticipate what others are going to do. If you're used to riding a bike, you'll have to adjust to the fact that the trike is wider than a bike, but that's just experience - some practice in a safe area with some cones would be prudent.

Comment: Are they really *that* hard to tip over? I’ve never ridden one, but looking at photos, the center of gravity (including the rider) is usually quite a bit higher than the width of the whole vehicle (and the single front wheel can make for some awkward handling). But of course you are correct that it’s up to the user to pay attention and ride safely, just like in any other vehicle.

Comment: If you want your dog to walk/run besides the trike, for part of the route if you go out for longer rides, you can get a special holder with a spring which you add to the frame and have a leash on it. They use it with quite big dogs but I am sure your small one will be safe enough even if you are not that stable on a bike/trike.

Answer (score 3):

12 Lb is about 5 kilograms.  You could carry your dog in a front basket on the handlebars perfectly well.  An old blanket or shirt makes for good disposable padding.  A wicker or fine mesh would be best, more open-weave basket could be scary.

I'd suggest using a chest harness and make sure its secured to the inside of the basket with a length that allows movement but stops the dog from jumping out in excitement.

A basket also allows the dog to see your face, whereas putting the dog behind on a tray means you can's see each other.

As for falling, if you manage to drop an adult tricycle, you're either in a full-on accident or riding quite aggressively.  This is quite unlikely.

Any bike shop should have baskets, or a cane/wicker weaver.  Consider weaving your own, but look at commercial examples for the mounting systems.

Comment: Alternate to front basket is something like the Buddyrider  (https://buddyrider.com/) that sits between the rider and handle bars. (not a product recommendation).

Comment: @mattnz thank you!   I knew that existed for kids, but not for pets.